# My apex method call doesn't works

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

[image]

This is the call, the apex method has two parameters, the fisrt is a date and the second is a list of strings, the methods works because i used it in the developer console and worked, is the called incorrect?
my apex method is emailExport.
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] to share a reproducible code example as text, not an image. I don't believe the snippet shown is enough to identify a problem. Please also review your logs and share any information found there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your property declaration is not correct, you should pass them as an object with key:value properties.

```
ApexMethodName({day: date, toEmails: emails})
.then( //do stuff =>
```